# Transaction and Lock MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need some clarity about transactions and lock on mysql

First. Need to do two or three inserts in diferent tables but if any of them fails cancel the whole operation. So here comes.

```
 START TRANSACTION
```

But before everything need the thread to be the unique to access those tables. Here it comes

```
 LOCK TABLES tab1 WRITE, tab2 WRITE
```

What should I do first?
Is it right to do it in this order?

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 LOCK TABLE....;

 INSERT INTO ...;
 if (something wrong)
 {
   ROLLBACK;
   UNLOCK TABLES;
   return;
 }

 INSERT INTO ...;
 if (something wrong)
 {
   ROLLBACK;
   UNLOCK TABLES;
   return;
 }

 COMMIT;
 UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This post has something of pseudo JAVA
Thank you very much.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? In most cases you do not have to lock the tables. InnoDB supports row level locking.

Comment: Check if a user name in tab1 is not used and email is not used in tab2 before even thinking about inserting new data. As new user signup is not that frequent i think I can afford an exclusive access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using transactions, table locking is automatically handled by the db engine. The use of explicit lock statements might even be detrimental to [transactional code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html):

> 13.3.5.1 Interaction of Table Locking and Transactions
>
> - LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES interact with the use of transactions as follows:
> - LOCK TABLES is *not transaction-safe* and implicitly commits any active transaction before attempting to lock the tables.
> - UNLOCK TABLES implicitly commits any active transaction, but only if LOCK TABLES has been used to acquire table locks. [...]

Although in your script pseudo code, you only use `LOCK TABLE` before any other command.

From a program logic stand point, which other functioanlity of your webapp might trigger an update on the same tables? If you only want to prevent an external update to occur while in transaction, proper [transaction isolation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html) (ie not `READ UNCOMMITED`)  should prevent any side effect to pervade.